Combine Blob trigger, input, output into 1 azure function v2 (python)
When I try to combine a blob trigger, input, output into 1 azure function v2 (python), it does not deploy and I don't see a specific error in the logs.
@app.blob_trigger(arg_name="myblob", path="old",connection="Storage") 
@app.blob_input(arg_name="inputblob", path="old/{name}.ifc",connection="Storage")
@app.blob_input(arg_name="outputblob", path="new/{name}.ifc",connection="Storage") 
def BlobTrigger(myblob: func.InputStream,inputblob: str,outputblob: func.Out[str]):
    logging.info(f'Python Queue trigger function processed {len(inputblob)} bytes')
    outputblob.set(inputblob)
    return "ok"

Any assistance on this would be appreciated?

Change blob_input to blob_output in the third line of the code.

As mentioned in the comments, you have @app.blob_input twice in the code.
Change the Code for Output binding to:
@app.blob_input(arg_name="outputblob", path="new/{name}.ifc",connection="Storage") 


I have implemented the same in my environment with the below code.
Code Snippet:
app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.blob_trigger(arg_name="myblob", path="old",connection="BlobStorageConnectionString") 
@app.blob_input(arg_name="inputblob", path="old/{name}.ifc",connection="Storage")
@app.blob_output(arg_name="outputblob", path="new/{name}.ifc",connection="Storage") 
def BlobTrigger(myblob: func.InputStream,inputblob: str,outputblob: func.Out[str]):
    logging.info(f'Python Queue trigger function processed {len(inputblob)} bytes')
    outputblob.set(inputblob)
    return "ok"


Run the function locally and make sure to sync the trigger before deploying the function to Azure.



Deployed to Azure:


